# Android SQLite RawQuery result always says it is found when it doesnt exist in database

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok, so I am clearly missing something when I look at this examples.  I have the following code which keeps returning the first if statement that the item is there, but it does it on anything I query.  I know they don't exist because some of the contents I am query against aren't even 12 characters and couldn't possibly match.  My understanding was using moveToFirst(); is either returning the result it matched, but the documentation says moveToFirst just moves it to the first row and weather it is successful. So, I think why it is always successful is because the cursor is created and the cursor does move to the first row.  If that is what is going on how do I just check if a value exist within my database? Thanks for your help, not sure why this is escaping me, I had it working the other day using the same method, but maybe I changed something.

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAMES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME = '" + contents +"'";
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contents = "The item" + contents +" is a valid.";
        tv.setText(contents);
    }else{
         contents = "The item " + contents + " is not a valid WIC item";
         tv.setText(contents);
    }
    close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query statement has some errors in it. please replace it with the following:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAMES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + "=" + contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `TABLE_NAMES` contains only one name ? if not the result will be true